# Issue in Tensor slicing operation

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to get `expected_out` from `input`.

```
input = [[2],[3],[3]]
expected_out = [2,3,3]
```

How to get the `expected_out` from `input` using TensorFlow.

Comment: do any of the answers help you?

Comment: yes. sorry for late respose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you want to remove single dimensional entries from a matrix. In both TensorFlow and Numpy, this operation is termed as `squeeze`.

Here is the official documentation for TensorFlow - [`tf.squeeze`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/shapes_and_shaping#squeeze). Quoting from the documentation,

> Given a tensor input, this operation returns a tensor of the same type with all dimensions of size 1 removed. If you don't want to remove all size 1 dimensions, you can remove specific size 1 dimensions by specifying axis

Hence to solve your issue, you can either pass `None` to `axis`, your default case, or pass `1`. Here is what the code will look like,

```
expected_out = tf.squeeze(input)
```

or,

```
expected_out = tf.squeeze(input, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [tf.squeeze](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/shapes_and_shaping#squeeze):

```
import tensorflow as tf

input = tf.constant([[2], [3], [3]])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(tf.squeeze(input)))
```